# Getting Segmentation fault at RET

Tags: c, assembly, segmentation-fault, 64-bit

I have the following header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
/**  **/

// size: 1B
typedef enum string_proc_func_type_t{
    REVERSIBLE      = 0,
    IRREVERSIBLE    = 1
} __attribute__((__packed__)) string_proc_func_type;


// size: 12B
typedef struct string_proc_key_t {
    uint32_t length; // 4B
    char* value; // 8B (ptr)
} __attribute__((__packed__)) string_proc_key; 
typedef void (*string_proc_func) (string_proc_key*);

// size 24B
typedef struct string_proc_list_t {
    char* name; // 8B (ptr)
    struct string_proc_node_t* first; // 8B (ptr)
    struct string_proc_node_t* last; // 8B (ptr)
} __attribute__((__packed__)) string_proc_list;

// size 33B
typedef struct string_proc_node_t {
    struct string_proc_node_t* next; // 8B (ptr)
    struct string_proc_node_t* previous; // 8B (ptr)
    string_proc_func f; // 8B (ptr)
    string_proc_func g; // 8B (ptr)
    string_proc_func_type type; // 1B
} __attribute__((__packed__)) string_proc_node;

string_proc_list* string_proc_list_create(char* name);
void string_proc_list_destroy(string_proc_list* list);

// Aux functions
uint32_t str_len(char* a);
char* str_copy(char* a);
```

I've already implemented aux functions as follows:

```
uint32_t str_len(char* a) { 
    uint32_t cont = 0;
    while(a != NULL && *a != '\0') {
        cont++;
        a++;
    }
    return cont;
}

char* str_copy(char* a) { 
    uint32_t length = str_len(a);
    char* copy = malloc(length);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        copy[i] = a[i];
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Now i want to implement `string_proc_list_create` function on Assembly, where i ended up with this:

```
; C functions
    extern malloc
    extern free
    extern fopen
    extern fclose
    extern fprintf
    extern str_copy

; structs sizes
    %define STRUCT_STRING_PROC_LIST_SIZE 24

; structs offsets
    %define STRUCT_STRING_PROC_LIST_NAME_OFFSET 0
    %define STRUCT_STRING_PROC_LIST_FIRST_OFFSET 8
    %define STRUCT_STRING_PROC_LIST_LAST_OFFSET 16
section .data


section .text

global string_proc_list_create
string_proc_list_create:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    push rdi ; save ptr to name

    ; allocate mem for struct
    mov rdi, STRUCT_STRING_PROC_LIST_SIZE
    sub rsp, 8 ; align stack
    call malloc
    add rsp, 8 ; unalign stack
    ; get ptr to struct at RAX

    pop rdi ; get ptr to name en RDI

    ; save ptr to struct at RBX 
    push rbx 
    mov rbx, rax

    ; copy name
    add rsp, 8 ; align stack
    call str_copy
    add rsp, 8 ; unalign stack
    ; get ptr to name (copy) at RAX

    ; initialize struct (ptr to struct at RBX, ptr to name (copy) at RAX)
    mov qword [rbx + STRUCT_STRING_PROC_LIST_NAME_OFFSET], rax
    mov qword [rbx + STRUCT_STRING_PROC_LIST_FIRST_OFFSET], 0
    mov qword [rbx + STRUCT_STRING_PROC_LIST_LAST_OFFSET], 0

    pop rbx
    pop rbp
    ret
```

Then, i try executing this line:

```
string_proc_list* list =  string_proc_list_create("aName");
```

But i'm getting a segmentation fault at RET. I think that i'm probably breaking the stack frame but i can't find what's wrong with my code. Any help?

Comment: Before the `call str_copy` you have an `add` instead of a `sub`. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Waw. I debugged and i didn't see that. So sorry and thanks!

Comment: The string you make with `str_copy()` doesn't have a null terminator.

Comment: @Barmar So i have to copy the ending char too? In my case, initializing the counter to 1 would do, right?

Comment: You have to add 1 to `str_len(a)` when calling `malloc`. And just append a null character after the loop.

Comment: POSIX has a built-in function `strdup()` that does this.

Comment: Why aren't you using the standard functions `strlen()` and `strcpy()`?

Comment: @Barmar Just to practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code you post, that is completely correct (if what you say is what you mean) but most probably where you use `str_copy`.  The problem is that you get a string that is not null terminated string.  You

```
uint32_t length = str_len(a);
char* copy = malloc(length);
```

when you have to `malloc(length+1);` to allow for a final `\0` char.
Then, you copy exactly length chars from the original string to the copy.  Then you should add a final `\0` char to the string, so it is well finished.

There's no problem in your code, but it generates not a string, but a char array with the valuable contents of the original string.  For it to be a proper string, you need to get space for a null char, and add it to the string, like this:

```
char* str_copy(char* a) { 
    uint32_t length_plus_1 = str_len(a) + 1; // enough for null to be included
    char* copy = malloc(length_plus_1);
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length_plus_1; ++i) {
        copy[i] = a[i];
    }
    return copy;
}
```